# Problem with the transport equation $u_x+u_t=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

For solving $u_t+u_x=0$

and given an initial condiion $u(x,0)=f(x)$

I can fix a point on the x-axis, $(x_0,0)$ and the line through this point, parallel to $x=t$ is given by $x=x_0+t$. Since our solution is constant along this line we must have

$u(x,t)=u(x_0+t,t)=u(x_0,0)$

But from the initial data $u(x_0,0)=f(x_0)$ where $f$ is known. So for any $(x,t)$:

$u(x,t)=f(x_0)=f(x-t)$

But if you add the following initial condition:

$u(0,t)=g(t)$ How do I adapt the solution I already have? or  I will have two solutions?

If I want my solution $ u (x, t) $ to be differentiable in a given set, does that impose conditions on the functions $ f $ and $ g $?

I really appreciate your time and help.

Comment: The condition $u(0, t) = g(t)$ shouldn't be thought of as an "initial" condition since it holds *at* a point in space ($x = 0$) for *all* time $t$. Since you have $f(x - t) = u(x, t)$, this implies $g(t) = u(0, t) = f(-t)$ so it looks like you must have $g(t) = f(-t)$ for these conditions to be compatible.

Answer (score 1):

What you are adding is not an initial condition, but a boundary condition at $x=0$. The initial condition is given for $x>0$.

The initial condition determines the solution only in the sector $x\ge t$. To determine the solution at a point with $x<t$ you should consider the characteristic with slope $=1$ through that point. Using the same reasoning as for the initial conditions, the value at such $(x,t)$ would be equal to the value at its point of intersection with the $t$-axis, and you know the values there thanks to your boundary condition. More precisely, if $x<t$ you will have $u(x,t)=g(t-x)$.

You cannot have initial conditions on the whole $x$ axis and boundary conditions, since (as Chris mentioned) they are generally incompatible.

Hope this helps.